# Use two UITableViews in one ViewController Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

How can i create two UITableViews in one ViewController , I have one problem

The problem you need every single to Return is not within the condition and I have information for each Tableview

This message : " Missing return in a function expected to return 'Int' "

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == table_View {
    return list.count
    }

    if tableView == table_View2 {
    return list_2.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == table_View {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_1") as! TableView_Cell
    cell.la_view.text = list[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Defeult")

    return cell
    }

    if tableView == table_View2 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_2") as! TableView_Cell
    cell.la_view2.text = list_2[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Defeult")

    return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: It's very bad idea to use a single data source for multiple table views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick solution (*please make sure to read the rest of the answer*), you could do it like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (tableView == table_View) ? list.count : list_2.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == table_View {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_1") as! TableView_Cell
        cell.la_view.text = list[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Defeult")

        return cell
    }

    if tableView == table_View2 { {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_2") as! TableView_Cell
        cell.la_view2.text = list_2[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Defeult")

        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

---

### Important Tip:

Keep in mind that if you have to add two table views in the same view controller (which should be *not* a pretty cool idea), you could *separate* handling the dataSource and delegate for each table view in a different class (not the same view controller that contains the table views). Example:

In your view controller, set the `dataSource` as:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let table_View = UITableView()
        let table_View2 = UITableView()

        table_View.dataSource = SourceHandler1()
        table_View2.dataSource = SourceHandler2()
    }
}
```

Therefore, implement:

```
class SourceHandler1: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_1") as! TableView_Cell
        cell.la_view.text = list[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Defeult")

        return cell
    }
}

class SourceHandler2: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        list_2.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_2") as! TableView_Cell
        cell.la_view2.text = list_2[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Defeult")

        return cell
    }
}
```

That leads to avoid the issue of "*massive*" view controller and reduce the possibility of producing [Spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

Answer (score 1):

The isse is, that e.g. `numberOfRowsInSection` has to return *something* in any case. In your implementation, you have two `if` statements, and you, but *only you* know that this is sufficient, because `tableView` can only be any of the two. Unfortuantely, the compiler does not know this. Therefore, you could either do it a simple way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == table_View {
        return list.count
    }
    return list_2.count
}
```

**Note:** same applies to `cellForRowAt` function

Maybe better:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == table_View {
        return list.count
    } else if tableView == table_View2 {
        return list_2.count
    } 
    assertionFailure("Unexpected tableView")
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code inside `numberOfRowsInSection` because of this delegate method required at least one `Int` value for a case. since you are using both value return in if condition, the error asking a value to return in else case. 
So each case should return an `Int` value.

```
 if tableView == table_View {
    return list.count
    } 
  else {
    return list_2.count
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == table_View {
        return list.count
    }

    if tableView == table_View2 {
        return list_2.count
    }
    return 0    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == table_View {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_1") as! TableView_Cell
        cell.la_view.text = list[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Defeult")

        return cell
    }

    if tableView == table_View2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_2") as! TableView_Cell
        cell.la_view2.text = list_2[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Defeult")

        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```